# Apache with mod_jk Tomcat change DNS Timeout (TTL)

Tags: tomcat, apache2, mod-jk

I'm using GSLB APP for geo-distribution and load-balancing.

The APP is Apache --> Tomcat througth **mod_jk** in workers.properties I have some like this:

worker.balancing.port=8009 
 **worker.balancing.host**=tomcats8009.gslb.domain.com 
 worker.balancing.type=ajp13 
 worker.balancing.socket_timeout=5

If Tomcat GSLB (tomcats8009.gslb.domain.com) changes from IP x.x.x.x to another IP y.y.y.y,  the dns resolution seems to be cached by the connector mod_jk and the request are still asking to x.x.x.x .

For solving I have to make "reload" to renew the resolution y.y.y.y.

Any idea? is there any kind of DNS caching in Apache or mod_jk connector? solutions?

Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is any property at mod_jk level but you can set it at the JDK level. Assuming you have Sun, the parameter would be "sun.net.inetaddr.ttl" ; setting it to zero would turn off dns caching. Generally this would not be recommended as turning off dns caching would affect performance.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, but I don't have JDK installed on this servers, it's only Server Webs (apaches). At Tomcats Server I have configurated at JAVA_PATH/security/java.security property networkaddress.cache.ttl and it's works very well. I need some similar to connector mod_jk.

Comment: In that case, I would think its coming from the OS. Assuming OS is Linux (or some flavor of Unix) is "nscd" enabled on your Apache web servers ?

Comment: All web servers are Debian as OS. I don't have nscd installed. and if i make a ping from a terminal it's respond the correct IP, when it's change.